# Подключение js на wordpress

Tags: jquery, javascript, wordpress

Значит, есть [меню](http://jsfiddle.net/7bu5gb9o/)  + jquery-2.1.1. Есть шаблон в wordpress. В нем файл `fun.php` c кодом:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="content">
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <div class="pageStyle">

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Как мне меню запихнуть в wordpress, чтоб все заработало? Пробовал в `header.php` писать

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/css/styleTab.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/tabs/tabs.js">
```

Не работает. Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css подключаются через `<link>`, а скрипты через `<script>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/css/styleTab.css" />
<script src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/tabs/tabs.js"></script>
```

И не забывайте закрывающий тэг у скрипта `</script>`, потому что из-за этого всё сломается и понять почему не так просто.

Comment: во дела...))а я уже пол дня сижу бошку ломаю что я не так делаю))) спасибо